# Saving and reading files to and from droplocation

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-sdk

I am currently trying to save the code-metrics results in an .xml file into the drop location of Team Foundation Server.

For saving I am using the following code snippet:

```
string outputLocation = Path.Combine(this.BuildDetail.DropLocation, "metrics.xml");
```

For showing the codemetrics results into an webapplication I have to read the codemetrics from the drop location.

Anyone knows the right way to do this??

Comment: How did you generate the XML and where did you output it to? If it's dropped in the Binaries folder, Team Build will automatically copy it to the DropLocation.

Comment: I'd generate the output with a code metrics power tool (http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20integrate%20the%20codemetric%20build%20activity&referringTitle=Documentation). I am pretty sure the Team Build did copy it to the DropLocation. I am having trouble reading the xml from the droplocation. It gives the following Exception Message: Exception Message: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\#\113\drop\metrics.xml'. (type DirectoryNotFoundException)

Comment: Which TFS version? What drop location have you configured for the build definition? It makes sense that c:\windows\System32 isn't a valid drop location.

Comment: I am using TFS version 2013. I didn't configure a location for the drop location. I assumed that's not necessary. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: If you don't configure a Drop location, then the logfiles are stored on the server, but all other files get removed. When you configure a drop location (on file share) then you should be able to fetch it using the method you've already found.

Comment: Thats it!, Thanks, i'd configure a drop location and got it working now on a on-premise version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've actually configured a drop location for your build. Team Build will only save the files that are saved tothe binaries directory if there is a drop location specified. Alternatively, since 2013, you can also drop your files in the `logs` directory. These files are saved on the TFS server and can be downloaded from the Web Access UI. I suspect that the `#\113\drop` is actually a pointer to that location.